# awk matching timestamp

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to match timestamp in awk. The regex that i have seems to work in grep, but not in awk

sample data:

```
12/21/17 20:11:57 data data data   #should match
12/21/17 20:12:18 data data data   #should match
12/21/17 20:12:20 data data data   #should match
12/21/2017 data data               #should not match
```

My grep seems to work:

```
grep -P "^(([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{2}\s([0-9]{1,2}:){2}[0- 9]{2})" file.txt
```

However, when I copy the same regex to awk, my awk failed. It basically won't recognize \s and beyond. I tried replacing \s with [[:blank:]] and [[:space:]] with no luck.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^(([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{2}\s([0-9]{1,2}:){2}[0-9]{2})/{if (p) print p; p=$0; next} p{p=p FS $0} END{print p}' file.txt
```

If I remove \s and the code after it(i.e. detecting only dates), it seems to work

```
awk '$1 ~ /^(([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{2}\s)/{if (p) print p ; p=$0; next} p{p=p FS $0} END{print p}' file.txt
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is this condition:

```
$1 ~ /^(([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{2}\s([0-9]{1,2}:){2}[0-9]{2})/
```

As you are matching across the fields `$1` is first field only.

You can use:

```
awk '/^(([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{2}\s([0-9]{1,2}:){2}[0-9]{2})/' file
```

However keep in mind that `\s` is only supported in `gnu-awk`.

To make it work on non-gnu awk, use `[[:blank:]]` instead of `\s`:

```
awk '/^(([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{2}[[:blank:]]+([0-9]{1,2}:){2}[0-9]{2})/' file
```